# React Exclude routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am adding a blog to my react app and I have to use slugs from the root such as

```
  export default new ClientModule({
  route: [
    <Route exact path="/posts" component={loadable(() => import('./containers/Post').then(c => c.default))} />,
    <Route exact path="/post/new" component={loadable(() => import('./containers/PostAdd').then(c => c.default))} />,
    <Route path="/post/:id" component={loadable(() => import('./containers/PostEdit').then(c => c.default))} />,
    <Route path="/:slug" component={loadable(() => import('./containers/PostBlog').then(c => c.default))} />
  ],
  navItem: [],
  resolver: [resolvers],
  localization: [{ ns: 'post', resources }]
});
```

/:slug is the slug of  a blog post. when I do this "/login" or "/signup" link goes to blog page and application crashes. Is there any way to exclude these paths from /:slug ?

These are my user routes

```
const NavLinkUsersWithI18n = translate('user')(({ t }) => (
  <NavLink to="/users" className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">
    {t('navLink.users')}
  </NavLink>
));
const NavLinkPostsWithI18n = translate('user')(({ t }) => (
  <NavLink to="/posts" className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">
    {t('navLink.posts')}
  </NavLink>
));
const NavLinkHabitsWithI18n = translate('user')(({ t }) => (
  <NavLink to="/habits" className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">
    {t('navLink.habits')}
  </NavLink>
));
const NavLinkLoginWithI18n = translate('user')(({ t }) => (
  <NavLink to="/login" className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">
    {t('navLink.signIn')}
  </NavLink>
));

export default new ClientModule({
  route: [
    <AuthRoute
      exact
      path="/profile"
      role={['user', 'admin']}
      redirect="/login"
      component={loadable(() => import('./containers/Profile').then(c => c.default))}
    />,
    <AuthRoute
      exact
      path="/users"
      redirect="/profile"
      role="admin"
      component={loadable(() => import('./containers/Users').then(c => c.default))}
    />,
    <AuthRoute
      exact
      path="/users/new"
      role={['admin']}
      component={loadable(() => import('./containers/UserAdd').then(c => c.default))}
    />,
    <AuthRoute
      path="/users/:id"
      redirect="/profile"
      role={['user', 'admin']}
      component={loadable(() => import('./containers/UserEdit').then(c => c.default))}
    />,
    <AuthRoute
      exact
      path="/register"
      redirectOnLoggedIn
      redirect="/profile"
      component={loadable(() => import('./containers/Register').then(c => c.default))}
    />,
    <AuthRoute
      exact
      path="/login"
      redirectOnLoggedIn
      redirect="/"
      component={loadable(() => import('./containers/Login').then(c => c.default))}
    />,
    <AuthRoute
      exact
      path="/forgot-password"
      redirectOnLoggedIn
      redirect="/profile"
      component={loadable(() => import('./containers/ForgotPassword').then(c => c.default))}
    />,
    <AuthRoute
      exact
      path="/reset-password/:token"
      redirectOnLoggedIn
      redirect="/profile"
      component={loadable(() => import('./containers/ResetPassword').then(c => c.default))}
    />
  ],
  navItem: [],
  navItemRight: [
    <IfLoggedIn key="/habits">
      <MenuItem>
        <NavLinkHabitsWithI18n />
      </MenuItem>
    </IfLoggedIn>,
    <IfLoggedIn key="/posts" role="admin">
      <MenuItem>
        <NavLinkPostsWithI18n />
      </MenuItem>
    </IfLoggedIn>,
    <IfLoggedIn key="/users" role="admin">
      <MenuItem>
        <NavLinkUsersWithI18n />
      </MenuItem>
    </IfLoggedIn>,
    <IfLoggedIn key="/profile">
      <MenuItem>
        <NavLink to="/profile" className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">
          <ProfileName />
        </NavLink>
      </MenuItem>
    </IfLoggedIn>,
    <IfLoggedIn key="/logout">
      <MenuItem>
        <LogoutLink />
      </MenuItem>
    </IfLoggedIn>,
    <IfNotLoggedIn key="/login">
      <MenuItem>
        <NavLinkLoginWithI18n />
      </MenuItem>
    </IfNotLoggedIn>
  ],
  resolver: [resolvers],
  localization: [{ ns: 'user', resources }],
  dataRootComponent: [DataRootComponent],
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
  rootComponentFactory: [req => (req ? <CookiesProvider cookies={req.universalCookies} /> : <CookiesProvider />)]
});
```

Comment: Can you do `/blog/:slug` instead?

Comment: Please show where you define the `<Route>`s for login and signup.

Comment: no I can't do that

Comment: I aded login signup user routes

Comment: I used to do this in rails and angular project, in here I can't figure it out

Comment: So you have two different `ClientModules`. Where are these used? How do you aggregate all of the routes?

Answer (score 0):

For other static paths, you'll need to define exact props. Eg.

```
<Route exact path="/signup"
```

And also make sure that dynamic path like `/:slug` appears later.

---

As per your updated question:

It will always satisfy to `/post/:id` and never let you go to `/:slug`. Because it has no exact props.

You should re-order the route for `/post/:id` later after `/:slug`.

---

To avoid such confusion on routing, I will suggest you simply define `/blog/:slug` instead and it won't matter for order with other routes.

Comment: they are not in the same module, I don't think I can should them in loading order, should I?